# Subscription Not Returning 201 Created HTTP Status Code

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to subscribe to a user's mailbox using Microsoft Graph subscriptions. I try to subscribe to a specific user's mailbox using the 'created' changeType only, which is being accessed via a token created using client credentials on my company's tenant in AD (app registration). This is being done in my dev environment (Laravel framework, using Laravel Valet + ngrok).

I can successfully create the subscription on MS's side, making the notification URL the ngrok URL and I am able to pass validation etc, but MS does not appear to return confirmation that the subscription has been created with a "201 Created" response like it says it should in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#response-1).

I can confirm myself that the subscription works because I can send an email to that mailbox and ngrok catches the request containing the correct information - just the initial setup of the webhook does not return 201 on successful creation.

I would like to have this confirmation so I can store the ID of the webhook etc in the application for further use (updating expiry on cron etc).

Apologies if I haven't submitted enough information to make the question clear - just ask for relevant details.

How should I proceed with this?

**EDIT - Including code examples and routing**

The code I use is a custom class so I cannot include everything but this is how it gets built:

**Microsoft.php**

```
    public function subscribe($resource)
    {
        $this->verb = "POST";

        $this->endpoint = "/subscriptions";

        $this->body = [
            "notificationUrl" => config('app.env') === 'production'
                ? env('APP_URL') . route('ms', null, false)
                : env('NGROK_URL') . route('ms', null, false),
            "resource" => $resource,
            "expirationDateTime" => Carbon::now('UTC')->addDay(),
            "latestSupportedTlsVersion" => "v1_2"
        ];

        return $this;
    }

    public function changes($array)
    {
        $this->body['changeType'] = implode(",", $array);

        return $this;
    }

    public function send()
    {
        $token = $this->getToken()->token;

        $this->headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer $token";

        try {
            $response = $this->client
                ->request($this->verb, env('GRAPH_BASE_URL') . $this->endpoint, [
                    'headers' => $this->headers,
                    'body' => json_encode($this->body, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)
                ]);

            return json_decode($response->getBody());
        } catch (RequestException $e) {
            echo Psr7\str($e->getRequest());
            if ($e->hasResponse()) {
                echo Psr7\str($e->getResponse());
            }
        }
    }
```

The code for the command that gets ran:

```
    public function handle()
    {
        $client = new MicrosoftClient();

        $webhookUrl = "users/" .
            env('AZURE_USER_ID') .
            "/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages";

        $changes = ['created'];

        $client->subscribe($webhookUrl)->changes($changes)->send();
    }
```

The POST route on my app logic:

```
Route::post('[my webhook url]', function (Request $request) {
    if ($request->query('validationToken')) {
        // MS requires that successful requests must send back a 200 status code
        // using a plain text response
        return response($request->query('validationToken', 200))
            ->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    } else {
        // just a regular webhook create/update...
        Log::info('Got email' . $request->input('value.resourceData'));
        Log::debug($request);
    }
})->name('ms');
```

^ in the else statement I put logs there to see if Laravel was catching any extra responses but the 201 was not there. The actual webhook notifications were being caught though.

This is a dump of the request before it is sent, JSON formatted for prettiness:

```
POST /v1.0/subscriptions HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/6.5.1 curl/7.68.0 PHP/7.4.3
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer [token]

{
  "notificationUrl":"[ngrok url]/[my chosen webhook endpoint]",
  "resource":"users/[user id]/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages",
  "expirationDateTime":"[24 hours after request made]",
  "latestSupportedTlsVersion":"v1_2",
  "changeType":"created"
}
```

This is what I get back from MS to validate the subscription:

```
POST /[my webhook url]?validationToken=Validation%3a+Testing+client+application+reachability+for+subscription+Request-Id%3a+262d7fae-31c3-4541-8de0-c1fc26ddd41b HTTP/1.1

Host: ticket-system.test:60
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
X-Forwarded-For: 40.113.95.219
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
X-Original-Host: [ngrok url]
```

This is the validation response I send back to MS (the validation token bit):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.15.11
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.3
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Date: Fri, 03 Apr 2020 08:42:34 GMT
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=[XSRF token]; expires=Fri, 03-Apr-2020 10:42:34 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/
Set-Cookie: [sluggified_app_name]_session=[session]; expires=Fri, 03-Apr-2020 10:42:34 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly


75

Validation: Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 262d7fae-31c3-4541-8de0-c1fc26ddd41b

0
```

And this is all ngrok appears to catch after all is said and done, a 200 response code which just appears to be the "validating" request before the webhook is to be created:

[Link to Webhook response example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFpRA.png) Sorry I can't post images on here because I am a new member.

As you can see I don't appear to get anything to confirm the webhook details.

Comment: could you include the php code for the subscription creation please? Also include when you are trying to read the response's body. Also what return code and response are you getting from the graph when creating the subscription?

Comment: @baywet I have updated my post with the info you requested. Please let me know if there is anything I have missed. The only return code I get is 200 (validation) and response includes the "Testing application reachability ..." body that I respond to successfully.

Comment: Thanks for adding the details, I can see a few gaps in the code. First in the post method body, you're not returning 202 accepted in case you're getting a notification and not a validation request.  Second, the webhook creation information is going to in the response to your creation request, not in the validation request. So you need to do something with the value returned by the last line of your handle method, this is where the information will be. Lastly it's possible that the validation handshake is not returning what the graph is expecting. You should look at the validation postman test

Comment: Here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#notification-endpoint-validation

Comment: Your 2nd point about doing something with the last line of the handle method was the main issue! Thank you so much! I am not sure why, but I expected the 201 response to come up in ngrok - but of course the response isn't going to end up there. Now I can put that straight into my DB.

Comment: glad I could help, added a recap as answer. Please mark it as answer for other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that the response from the subscription creation request is not used (logged, stored, etc...) from looking at the code. (last line of handle method).
As described in the comments the subscription information will be in the response, not in the validation request coming to the endpoint.